# Hiding specific rows in excel without formula

Tags: excel, rows

Is there a way in MS Excel 2007 where I can hide a row in excel that contains a specific value? For example if cell B1 contains number 6, the entire 1st row will be hidden.

Comment: This will require VBA or manually hiding rows

Answer (score 1):

NOT *with* formula.

Formulae don't do that sort of thing. With formulae about the closest to your desired result might be to apply conditional formatting to 'hide' the *contents* of the entire 1st row - by blending their font colour into that of the text background, or 'redact' - if say black font then applying black fill.

Try VBA.